# Need code to move data from one sheet to another(VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I basically need to move data from one sheet to another in VBA. I attached photos with an example of the sheet containing the data to be moved(Sheet1), as well as the destination sheet(Sheet2). I need the code to read the first row, and post PP under the PP column, the date under the production date column, the employee name under the name column, the activity (mopping, cleaning, scrubbing, wiping) under the task ID column, and the number of activities done under the "How many?" column. I wrote a few lines manually in "sheet2" of the attached photos, but it would make my life a lot easier if I could automate the process. If my explanation is unclear, feel free to contact me with questions:)

Source:
[image: Pic of source sheet/data]

Destination:
[image: destination sheet]

Comment: I feel like maybe if you get rid of those subtotal rows and just toss that a pivottable you would be able to get at this pretty quick.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to have a VBA code written to do this :(

Comment: How about making the destination sheet equal to source. Like: `WS2.Range("A2:AD10").Value =WS1.Range("A2:AD10).Value`

Comment: @XLmatters I definitely will do that :) The part that I cannot figure out is how to write code to prompt excel to go down a row and pick up data while ignoring blank cells.

Answer (score 1):

I would be great if you share some code or trys... here is some code you can work from, I hope it helps (I am assuming the sheet1, starts in column A... as we can't see the column headers on your screenshot):

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wsSource, wsDestination As Worksheet
Dim i, LastRowS, LastRowD As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook.Name
wsSource = wb.Sheets("Hoja1")
wsDestination = wb.Sheets("Hoja2")

LastRowS = wsSource.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

EmployeeName = wsSource.Cells(3, 3).Value

t = 7

Do Until t = LastRowS

    For i = 5 To 8

    LastRowD = wsDestination.Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

        If wsSource.Cells(t, j).Value > 0 Then

        wsDestination.Cells(LastRowD + 1, 2).Value = EmployeeName
        wsDestination.Cells(LastRowD + 1, 3).Value = wsSource.Cells(t, 1).Value
        wsDestination.Cells(LastRowD + 1, 4).Value = wsSource.Cells(t, 2).Value
        wsDestination.Cells(LastRowD + 1, 5).Value = wsSource.Cells(6, j).Value
        wsDestination.Cells(LastRowD + 1, 7).Value = wsSource.Cells(t, j).Value

        End If

    Next

t = t + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I will modify that code until it works for me:) This was the code I had written at first, but I am god awful at coding and it did not work how I wanted it to:(